# How to get rid of "\\" in Nlog messages?

Tags: elasticsearch, nlog

I'm using Nlog to log messages to Elasticsearch. The messages often contain file path names. Nlog seems to escape the "\" character in every file path and I want to  avoid that. The encode="false" attribute doesn't work with the "field" tag used to configure the Elasticsearch target. Is there any other way to store a file path without the extra "\"?

Comment: ` Nlog seems to escape the "\" character in every file path`, not sure about that. Could you please post an example? (config and logger calls)

Answer (score 1):

I've searched through the docs more thoroughly and come across the Replace Layout Renderer. Here is what appears to be working in my case:

```
<variable name="replacedstring" value="${replace:searchFor=\\:wholeWords=false:replaceWith=/:regex=false:inner=${message}}" />
```

You simply define the variable in the Nlog.config file and use it where you'd normally use the layout containing the pre-modified string (the inner attribute). I hope that's what I was looking for. I was also wondering if it is possible to define multiple patterns within the same variable. For example,we want to replace "\" with "/" and at the same time we want to replace "\r\n" with "-" across the same inner string. Does anyone know if that is possible using this particular renderer? The docs say nothing about it.

Comment: For newlines you can checkout: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Replace-NewLines-Layout-Renderer